# fixed menu scroller with scrollbar and stop on top

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

Menu (black color) is fixed position with offset margin top height of header. Menu offset top margin goes up on scroll but It should also stop when reaches on top.
[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/g6wfy740/7/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
  var bgp = $(window).scrollTop();
   var result =  headerHeight-bgp;

  if(y > 0 ){
      $('.menu').css({'top': + result +'px'});  
  } else{
    $('.menu').css({'top': + headerHeight +'px'}); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Please read this and consider improving your question: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes. I have read all Stack overflow terms and condition. But in this question the kind of issue I had. I was able to elaborate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your expected output:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      var y = $(window).scrollTop();
      var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
      var bgp = $(window).scrollTop();
      //var mtv = $('.menu').position().top;
       var result =  headerHeight-bgp;

      if(result > 0 ){
          $('.menu').css({'top': + result +'px'});  

      } else{
          console.log("stop");
        $('.menu').css({'top':  0}); 
      }
    });
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/g6wfy740/9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        var result =  150-y;

        if(result > 0 ){
            $('.menu').css({'top': + result +'px'});  
        } else{
            $('.menu').css({'top': + 0 +'px'}); 
        }
    });
```

Doing it much easier way.  https://jsfiddle.net/g6wfy740/10/